# Repeated measures in messy format, need help to tidy

Tags: r

I have a very large data set containing weekly weights that have been coded with week of study and the weight at that visit. There are some missing visits and the data is not currently aligned.

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:3, Week_A=c(6,6,7), Weight_A=c(23,24,23), Week_B=c(7,7,8), 
                 Weight_B=c(25,26,27), Week_C=c(8,9,9), Weight_C=c(27,26,28)) 

df
  ID Week_A Weight_A Week_B Weight_B Week_C Weight_C
1  1      6       23      7       25      8       27
2  2      6       24      7       26      9       26
3  3      7       23      8       27      9       28
```

I would like to align the data by week number (ideal output below).

```
df_ideal <- data.frame (ID=1:3, Week_6=c(23,24,NA), Week_7=c(25,26,23), 
                        Week_8=c(27,NA,27), Week_9=c(NA,26,28))

df_ideal
  ID Week_6 Week_7 Week_8 Week_9
1  1     23     25     27     NA
2  2     24     26     NA     26
3  3     NA     23     27     28
```

I would appreciate some help with this, even to find a starting point to manipulate this data to an easier to manage format.

Comment: Does the "A", "B", "C" suffix have any meaning at all?

Comment: It represents sequential measures, ideally every ID would get weighed every week, but as per the example above, some ID's miss weekly weights (i.e. ID 2 doesn't have a weight at week 8). This is the way the data was entered. The suffixes don't have any meaning other than to differentiate the data (so weight 'B' occurred at week 'B', and so so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tidyverse solution:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:3, 
                 Week_A=c(6,6,7), 
                 Weight_A=c(23,24,23), 
                 Week_B=c(7,7,8), 
                 Weight_B=c(25,26,27),
                 Week_C=c(8,9,9),
                 Weight_C=c(27,26,28))

library(tidyverse)
df_long <- df %>% gather(key="v", value="value", -ID) %>% 
  separate(v, into=c("v1", "v2")) %>% 
  spread(v1, value) %>% 
  complete(ID, Week) %>% 
  arrange(Week, ID)

df_long
# A tibble: 12 x 4
#      ID  Week v2    Weight
#   <int> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1     1     6 A         23
# 2     2     6 A         24
# 3     3     6 <NA>      NA
# 4     1     7 B         25
# 5     2     7 B         26
# 6     3     7 A         23
# 7     1     8 C         27
# 8     2     8 <NA>      NA
# 9     3     8 B         27
#10     1     9 <NA>      NA
#11     2     9 C         26
#12     3     9 C         28

df_wide <- df_long %>% select(-v2) %>% 
  spread(Week, Weight, sep="_")
df_wide
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#     ID Week_6 Week_7 Week_8 Week_9
#  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1     23     25     27     NA
#2     2     24     26     NA     26
#3     3     NA     23     27     28
```

Personally, I'd keep using df_long instead of df_wide, as it is a `tidy` data frame, while df_wide is not.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. I understand the utility in keeping it as a `tidy` data frame, and will try and do further analysis using tidy data.

Comment: Since you commented that A, B, C suffix is used to match week & weight columns, I suppose there may be more such suffixes, it'd be better to replace `Week_A:Weight_C` in my code with `-ID` (gather all columns other than `ID`), so the code is more generic. I made this edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach using the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
#convert into a data.table
setDT(df)

#convert into a long format
mdat <- melt(df, id.vars="ID", measure.vars=patterns("^Week", "^Weight", cols=names(df)))

#pivot into desired output
ans <- dcast(mdat, ID ~ value1, value.var="value2")
```

`ans` output:

```
   ID  6  7  8  9
1:  1 23 25 27 NA
2:  2 24 26 NA 26
3:  3 NA 23 27 28
```

And if you really need the "Week_" in your column names, you can use

```
setnames(ans, names(ans)[-1L], paste("Week_", names(ans)[-1L]))
```

Comment: The column names can be renamed directly in the `dcast()` call by specifying an expression for the RHS of the formula: `dcast(mdat, ID ~ paste0("Week_", value1), value.var="value2")
`

Answer (score 1):

Another `tidyverse` solution using a double-`gather` with a final `spread`

```
df %>%
    gather(k, v, -ID, -starts_with("Weight")) %>%
    separate(k, into = c("k1", "k2")) %>%
    unite(k1, k1, v) %>%
    gather(k, v, starts_with("Weight")) %>%
    separate(k, into = c("k3", "k4")) %>%
    filter(k2 == k4) %>%
    select(-k2, -k3, -k4) %>%
    spread(k1, v)
#  ID Week_6 Week_7 Week_8 Week_9
#1  1     23     25     27     NA
#2  2     24     26     NA     26
#3  3     NA     23     27     28
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, it's a double `reshape`, firstly to long and then back to wide on a different variable:

```
tmp <- reshape(df, idvar="ID", varying=lapply(c("Week_","Weight_"), grep, names(df)),
               v.names=c("time","Week"), direction="long")
reshape(tmp, idvar="ID", direction="wide", sep="_")

#    ID Week_6 Week_7 Week_8 Week_9
#1.1  1     23     25     27     NA
#2.1  2     24     26     NA     26
#3.1  3     NA     23     27     28
```